# How to post a form to a switch statement to display a value in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, switch-statement

what I need help with today is "How do I submit a form, so that if a certain value is selected, it will display a echo" - Here is what I have so far, but no data is being displayed:

```
<form action="shop.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip1">VIP Package 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip2">VIP Package 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="order" value="vip3">VIP Package 3<br />
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="order"/>-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <center><?php
        if(isset($_GET['order']))
            {
        switch($_GET['order']) {
        case NULL:
            echo'';
            //echo'<b>No payment was selected!</b>';
            break;

        case 'vip1':
            echo '12321';
            break;

        case 'vip2':
            echo 'You must be rich :D';
            break;

        case 'vip3':
            echo 'This is test 2!';
            break;

        case 'vip4':
            echo 'This is test 3!';
            break;
                } 
                    } else { echo '<b></b>'; }
```

Now, I have looked around google and StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I tried watching a video but I don't understand how it works, since I am using radio buttons for my options. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: IGNORE PREVIOUS MESSAGE - Is there any way this code can be fixed up/cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`<form>`** method is `post` , but you are accessing with **`$_GET`**. Change that to **`$_POST`**.

See here

```
 if(isset($_GET['order'])) // Must be $_POST
```

Change all those occurences from `$_GET` to `$_POST`

Comment: Worked, cheers. Much appreciated. So to clarify, if something's being sent VIA POST, it must grab it as a POST? Not GET?

Comment: IGNORE PREVIOUS MESSAGE - Is there any way this code can be fixed up/cleaned?

Comment: Move that `form` code on top inside the else statement of your `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

So as the user selects an option, and hits the submit button, the process page will process what he/she has chosen and redirect back to the index with a message of what the user has selected and it will display what the user has selected. It's pretty simple.

Your index.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['item']) && strlen($_GET['item'])>0) {
if($_GET['item'] == 1) {
echo "You have chosen VIP Package 1!";
}
if($_GET['item'] == 2) {
echo "You have chosen VIP Package 2!";
}
if($_GET['item'] == 3) {
echo "You have chosen VIP Package 3!";
}
if($_GET['item'] == "none") {
echo "You have not chosen anything!";
}
}

<form action="shop.php" method="post" name="submit">
        <input type="radio" name="order1" value="vip1">VIP Package 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="order2" value="vip2">VIP Package 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="order3" value="vip3">VIP Package 3<br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your shop.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$order1 = $_POST['order1'];
$order2 = $_POST['order2'];
$order3 = $_POST['order3'];
if(empty($order1) && empty(order2) && empty (order3)) {
header("Location: index.php?item=none");
}
if($order1 == 1) {
header("Location: index.php?item=1");
}
else {
}
if($order2 == 1) {
header("Location: index.php?item=2");
}
else {
}
if($order3 == 1) {
header("Location: index.php?item=3");
}
else {
}
}
?>
```